# Need help figuring out why my PHP keep spitting out google captcha is not set

Tags: javascript, php, html

Someone help me figuring out as why my PHP always spitting out google recaptcha as not being set. It failed at **echo "recaptcha_empty"**. Thanks in advance and
ignore the google api key.

> if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]))
>
> PHP Code

```html
 <?php

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["phone"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {

    if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {
        $username = $_POST["name"];
        $useremail = $_POST["email"];
        $userphone = $_POST["phone"];
        $usermessage = $_POST["message"];

        $to = "mail@domain.com";
        $subject = "Inquiry form MKM Website";
        $message = "From: $username\n E-Mail: $useremail\n Phone: $userphone\n\n\n Message:\n\n $usermessage";
        $header = "Generated by MKM Website";

        // your secret key
        $secretKey = "secret_key";
        $captcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $response = json_decode($verify, true);

        // if submitted check response
        if ($response["success"] != false) {
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
                echo "success";
            } else {
                echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
                exit;
            }

        } else {
            echo "recaptcha_fail";
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        echo "recaptcha_empty";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "Form can not be empty..!!";
    exit;
}
```

> JAVAScript Code

```html
function submitForm() {
    var reply = getId("reply");
    reply.innerHTML = "<h4>Sending message...</h4>";

    var name = getId("user-name");
    var email = getId("user-email");
    var phone = getId("user-phone");
    var messa = getId("user-message");

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("name", name.value);
    formdata.append("email", email.value);
    formdata.append("phone", phone.value);
    formdata.append("message", messa.value);

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "contact.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        switch(ajax.readyState) {
            case 1:
                reply.innerHTML = "<h4>Loading.</h4>";
                break;

            case 2:
                reply.innerHTML = "<h4>Loading..</h4>";
                break;

            case 3:
                reply.innerHTML = "<h4>Loading...</h4>";
                break;
        }

        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if (ajax.responseText === "success") {
                getId("reply").innerHTML = '<h4>Thanks ' + name.value + ', your message has been sent.</h4>';
                name.value = "";
                email.value = "";
                phone.value = "";
                messa.value = "";
            } else if (ajax.responseText === "recaptcha_empty") {
                getId("reply").innerHTML = '<h5>Please tick the captcha box.</h5>';
            } else if (ajax.responseText === "recaptcha_fail") {
                getId("reply").innerHTML = '<h5>Recaptcha fail.. please try again later.</h5>';
            } 
            else {
                getId("reply").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function getId(_str) {
    return document.getElementById(_str);
}
```

> HTML FORM

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user-name" id="user-name" placeholder="Your name" required>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user-email" id="user-email" placeholder="Your email address" required>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user-phone" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Phone</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="user-phone" id="user-phone" placeholder="Your phone number" required>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
         <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="5" placeholder="Your message - max 200 characters" maxlength="200" required></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="reply" class="text-center"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: `<  ? php` INVALID PHP TAG

Comment: You form not have the 'g-recaptcha-response' name input.

Comment: And you dont seem to add `g-recaptcha-response` into your formdata

Comment: @RiggsFolly i mess the php tag when i edit it for stack overflow version. The tag is fine on my actual server. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Hi, **g-recaptcha-response into your formdata** <<< i think that was the issue. Can you show me an example?

Comment: I figured, after the Google captcha fully loaded it creat an iframe with id="g-recaptcha-response". I just have to put them in a variable and push it in ajax so it visible globally for my php. Thanks for the hint.